# Accessing javascript array from function

Tags: php, jquery

Okay, so in my `<head>` section i have the following:

```
<script>
    var userDefaultInfo = '<?=$userInfo;?>';
    var jGets = new Array ();
    <?
    if(isset($_GET)) {
        foreach($_GET as $key => $val)
            echo "jGets[\"$key\"]=\"$val\";\n";
    }
    ?>
</script>
```

Now In my external .JS file, In the $(document).ready() section I can access userDefaultInfo fine, however, I am trying to access jGets, but not directly from there.

in the external .JS file, outside of $(document).ready(); I have the following function:

```
var sendGET = function () {
    var data = $(this).val();
    var elementName = $(this).attr("name");
    var url = "zephi.php?p=home/support/admin_support.php&"+elementName+"="+data;
    jQuery.each(jGets, function(i, val) {
           alert(val);
        });
    alert(url);
    window.location = url;
}
```

When a user changes a  box, this function fires and changes the window location using the  data.  However, I want to add the data in the variable `jGets`, but I do not seem to be able to reference it at all in there.

Why is this?

Comment: Looks like `sendGET()` in the external JS file gets called before `jGets` is defined within the actual page. In your function do `typeof(jGets)` to see if it's undefined.

Comment: which is called first? the external JS code or your js script in head section?

Comment: well i have the script section in my header and then right after that my external .JS file is called.

Comment: Just so you know `var jGets = new Array ();` and then assign named keys like it's an _"associative array"_ doesn't qualify as good JS: arrays are numerically indexed, always. If you want named keys (aka properties), you're working with an object: `var jGets = new Object()` would be better. But even so, best of all: don't use the constructors at all, either user `var anArray = [];` or `var anObject = {};`

Comment: Hmm, thanks @EliasVanOotegem, I will read up on javascript objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're "mis"-using an `Array` as an `Object`.

```
var jGets = {};
```

Comment: Aha, thank you very much.  It is showing the values now, all I had to do was change that! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps doing either one of the following might work:

```
echo 'var jGets = '.(isset($_GET) ? preg_replace('/^"|"$/','',json_encode($_GET)) : '{}').';'
//or
echo 'var jGets = JSON.parse('.isset($_GET) ? json_encode($_GET); : '"{}"'.');'
```

This will produce an object literal, assigning everything you need to `jGets`, without having to mess about with loops. Since `JSON` stands for `JavaScript Object Notation`, it seems only logical/natural to use that to set the variable accordingly. Read more on `json_encode` [here](http://www.php.net/json_encode), more on `JSON` in PHP can be found [here](http://www.php.net/json)